# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.0 :How to pass html as a string using JAVA?

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

Can we use a String instead of content.html file in the below command:

wkhtmltopdf --header-html  header.html content.html cover cover.html a.pdf

In my code, there is a html template which could copy its content into a separate html file and add dynamic content to it. So for every request, new separate unique HTML file would be created and so it would eat up disk space. Instead of that, I am thinking to copy that dynamic HTML content to a String and use it directly in to the command.

so does WKHTMLTOPDF support below command?

wkhtmltopdf --header-html  header content.html cover cover.html a.pdf

where header is a STRING that contains HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string for content.html! You need to feed the string via the STDIN stream and use a command like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf --header-html header.html - cover cover.html a.pdf
```

Then in Java you need to create a Stream, point that stream to the wkhtmltopdf Process, vomit your string into the stream and let it do its work.

As for the header, at least 0.11 does not support that. I use tempfiles for headers, footers, TOC files and cover pages in 0.11.